# best practice for sending data using intent to other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, cursor

i created a listview with video thumbnail
i already know how to use the media info and how to list it.

my question is what is the best programming practice for
sending media info like String, Integer, or even a Bitmap?

Parcelable or Seralizeable or just ID of it from cursor?

i want to maximize my speed performance of my apps,

they say parce is good, some seializeable but others programers
say its best to just only pass the ID or the position for cursor than using objects
etc..

which is good from these 3?

1. Parcelable
2. Seralizeable
3. just ID cursor etc, or position of the list?

example:

ACTIVITY A

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // MOVE TO CLICK POSITION
        videoCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        // GET THE COLUMN INDEX OF THE FILEPATH, TITLE, ARTIST, DURATION
        videoPathColumnIndex = videoCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        videoTitleColumnIndex = videoCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
        videoArtistColumnIndex = videoCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST);
        videoDurationColumnIndex = videoCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        videoImageColumnIndex = videoCursor.getInt(videoCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

        // LIST THE DATA FROM STRING OF THE COLUMNINDEX OF THE VIDEOCURSOR POSITION
        videoPath = videoCursor.getString(videoPathColumnIndex);
        videoTitle = videoCursor.getString(videoTitleColumnIndex);
        videoArtist = videoCursor.getString(videoArtistColumnIndex);
        videoDuration = videoCursor.getString(videoDurationColumnIndex);

        // START THE NEW INTENT ACTIVITY AND PASS SOME MEDIA INFO
        videoIntent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
        videoIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_PATH, videoPath);
        videoIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_TITLE, videoTitle);
        videoIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_ARTIST, videoArtist);
        videoIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_DURATION, videoDuration);

        startActivity(videoIntent);
    }
```

this my code i can send the title, the path, the artist, i can also play the video through path, if i want to send the VideoThumbnail using the id only how to use putExtra and send the ID and get from ACTIVITY B and used the data?

Answer (score 1):

If your object is already persisted in a database, then of course go with the ID. If not, *Parcelable* is recommended over *Serializable* as it is more performant. On this blog post http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/ the author did some benchmark to compare the two methods.

TL;DR Implementing the Serializable interface is slower because it uses reflection under the hood.

[By the way *Bitmap* already implements the *Parcelable* interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), but be careful when passing heavy objects from one activity to the other as it would require a lot of memory. It's really a judgement call that you would have to make.

Comment: ok il try the id, if i want to pass the id of the videothumbnail image from cursor how can i get the id from the other activity and asign it again to new bitmap? can you give me simple code for that, thnks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the least you can, also because it makes it clearer what you are actually sending. If the data you want to send is covered by one of the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) methods, use that. For example, if you have a `String` use `putString`. If you have an enum or an ID you can use in your new Activity or Fragment, use `putInt` (with `ordinal()` on the enum).

Only if you have e.g. a custom object there's really a need for a Parcelable object. Some Android specific classes already implement the Parcelable interface. I would avoid `Serializable` since it's slower and you usually have no real control over the serialization.

Comment: so sending Primitive Data Types is NOT heavy compare to Object like ImageView, Bitmap? so if its heavy il just use ID of that coresponding list so that the class that will receive will only create a new objects base from the IDs?

Comment: If you have the data persisted, it's definitely always not as heavy (and therefore easier on the memory / faster) to just pass the ID of your data as a primitive type and let the target fetch it when necessary, than passing the data itself, yes. Only if it was e.g. a long-lasting / CPU intensive  etc. process to get the data you have, than you might reconsider.

Comment: ok il show my codes try to see if how to send id and recieve and gets the value from other activity. il show you from the top example